# Tailwind CSS class "w-full xl:w-3/6" doesn't work at xl breakpoint

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I can't get this code to work on vuejs, class `xl:w-3/6` doesn't override `w-full`.

I tried replacing `w-full` with `sm:w-full` but when the window is smaller than `sm` the class doesn't apply.

How can I get this to work properly?

Comment: What's the tailwind version you use? Did you override the default configuration of tailwind? What's the viewport width you used in order to test that `xl:w-3/6` should be used?

Comment: The tailwind version is `^3.0.23`. I didn't override anything, I didn't change the default configuration. I have a 1080p screen.
What I'm saying is `w-full` overrides `xl:w-3/6`, if it was for bootstrap: `xl` would override `w-full` at (min-width: 1280px).

Comment: I've run into similar cascade issues. You could try `w-full xl:w-[50%]` to see if the priority is respected when using custom values.

Comment: It works fine in Tailwind Play https://play.tailwindcss.com/1QJH23WJH9 so it must be your config or your setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
class="w-full xl:!w-3/6"
```

Here we apply the [important modifier](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#important-modifier) in tailwind CSS inorder to override the default behaviour of the class `w-full`

From the docs...

> The `!` always goes at the beginning of the utility name, after any
> variants, but before any prefix:
>
> ```
> <div class="sm:hover:!tw-font-bold">
> ```
>
> This can be useful in rare situations where you need to increase
> specificity because **you’re at war with some styles you don’t control**.

Comment: Wow, you nailed it man 